# Concatenation of std::string and int leads to a shift. Why?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, concatenation

Today I was surprised when trying to concatenate an `std::string` with an `int`. Consider the following MWE:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void print(const std::string& text)
{
    std::cout << "The string is: " << text << ".\n";
}

int main()
{
    print("iteration_" + 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Instead of printing

```
The string is: iteration_1.
```

which I would expect, it prints

```
The string is: teration_.
```

What *exactly* is going on in the background? Does the string for some reason get converted into `char[]` or something of the sort? The [documentation of operator+](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+/) does not list any with an `std::string` and `int`.

And what is the proper way of concatenating an `std::string` with a number? Do I really have to throw them both into an `std::stringstream` or convert the number into `std::string` explicitely with `std::to_string()`?

Comment: Yes, you have to convert `1` to a string in order to append it to a string. Other languages do all sorts of conversions behind your back; C++ generally tries to make this sort of thing explicit, in order to make it easier to understand what your code is actually doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the string for some reason get converted into char[]

Actually it is the other way around. `"iteration_"` is a `char[11]` which decays to a `const char*` when you add `1`. Incrementing the pointer by one makes it point to the next character in the string. This is then used to construct a temporary `std::string` that contains all but the first character.

The documentation you link is for `operator+` of `std::string`, but to use that you need a `std::string` first.

Answer (score 2):

This line is the problem:

```
print("iteration_" + 1);
```

The string literal is decaying to a `char*`. You are adding `1` to this `char*`, moving it to the next character.

If you wanted to add the string `"1"` to the end of your literal, a fairly simple way is to pass the string literal to the `std::string` constructor and convert the `1` to a string manually. For example:

```
print(std::string("iteration_") + std::to_string(1));
```

Comment: @idclev463035818 realised my mistake just after posting, corrected, thanks :)

Comment: Why the `std::string` constructor? Isn't `print("iteration_" + std::to_string(1));` enough?

Comment: @DominikMokriš just a preference to being explicit :)

Answer (score 2):

`"iteration_"` is not `std::string`, but `const char[]`. Which decays to `const char*`, and `"iteration_" + 1` just performs pointer arithmetic and move the pointer pointing to the next `char` (i.e. `'t'`), then you got the c-style string `"teration_"`.

You can use [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to convert `int` to `std::string`, then concatenate them. e.g.

```
print("iteration_" + std::to_string(1));
```

For this case [std::operator+(std::basic_string)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) is called and the 1st argument `"iteration_"` is converted to `std::string` implicitly and then passed to `operator+`, then the concatenated `std::string` is passed to `print`.

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Fdd93H0OF62Ew5lc)

Answer (score 1):

If you try to use the following:

```cpp
std::string str = "iteration" + 1;
```

compiler will throw the warning:

> warning: adding 'int' to a string does not append to the string
>   [-Wstring-plus-int]

It is because you are incrementing the pointer to "iteration" string by 1 which means that now "teration" string is being assigned to `str` variable.

The proper way of concatenating would be:

```cpp
std::string str = "iteration" + std::to_string(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression `"iteration_" + 1` is a `const char[11]` literal added to the `int` 1.

In that expression, `"iteration_"` *decays* to a `const char*` *pointer* to the first element of the array. `+ 1` then takes place in pointer arithmetic on that pointer. The entire expression evaluates to a `const char*` type (pointing to the first `t`) which is a valid NUL-terminated input to a `std::string` constructor! (The anonymous temporary `std::string` *binds* to the `const std::string&` function parameter.)

This is completely valid C++ and can occasionally be put to good use.

If you want to treat `+` as a concatenation, then

```
print("iteration_" + std::to_string(1));
```

is one way.